# Как сделать что бы модуль импортировал подмодули?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Как сделать чтобы модуль импортировал подмодули Python 3?

Есть например проект со структурой:

[image: Структура]

Смысл такой, я хочу при запуске GUI.py из папки report импортировать класс из report.py, который бы в свою очередь импортировал класс из calc_base.py из папки base_class. Он выдает ошибку "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_class'"
Сам пример проекта прикрепляю [ссылка на пример проекта](https://yadi.sk/d/TbBAUBuaYLAVVg)

Да можно было бы вообще в одной папке все расположить =) Вопрос чисто технический , можно-ли так делать и делают ли так? И если можно сделать то как?

.********дополнение********_____
в файле calc_base.py из папки base_class есть класс

```
class Flow_rate:
def __init__(self, diametr_hole = 2000):
    self.diametr_hole = diametr_hole

def flow_rate_liquid(self, diametr_hole = 200):
    
    flow_rate_liquid = diametr_hole*2

    return flow_rate_liquid
```

Который что бы импортировать на уровень выше в report.py папки report я использую init.py из папки base_class

```
from .calc_base import Flow_rate
```

Дальше в самом `report.py` я импортирую функцию из класса выше  для использования ее в новой функции `flow_str`:

```
from base_class import Flow_rate

class Report:

    def flow_str():
    
        flow = Flow_rate().flow_rate_liquid(diametr_hole = 200)
        flow_str = str(flow)+" Go!"
    
        return flow_str
```

Вот до этого момента все нормально)

А вот когда я хочу по той же схеме через `init.py` папки report импортировать класс на уровень выше в `GUI.py`

```
from .report import Report
```

А самом GUI.py пишу

```
from report import Report
```

выдает ошибку: `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_class'"` .

Т.е. я так понял он не собирает все  `init.py` по пути.

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который содержит три вышеперечисленных модуля, обычным текстом в вопросе (не ссылкой). Покажите как вы делаете импорты, которые приводят к ошибке, о которой вы пишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**GUI.py**

```
print("GUI.py")

from report.report  import Report       # report.py
  

report = Report()

flow_str = report.flow_str()

print(f'flow_str = {flow_str}')
```

**report.py**

```
from report.base_class.calc_base import Flow_rate           # calc_base.py

print('report.py')

class Report:
    def __init__(self):                                           # +++
        self.flow = Flow_rate()                                   # +++
        

    def flow_str(self):                                           # +++ self !!!
#        flow = Flow_rate().flow_rate_liquid(diametr_hole = 200)
        flow = self.flow.flow_rate_liquid(diametr_hole = 300)     # 300
        flow_str = str(flow)+" Go!"
    
        return flow_str
```

**calc_base.py**

```
print("calc_base.py")

class Flow_rate:

    def __init__(self, diametr_hole=2000):
        self.diametr_hole = diametr_hole

    def flow_rate_liquid(self, diametr_hole=200):
        flow_rate_liquid = diametr_hole * 2
        return flow_rate_liquid
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спросите, если что-то будет не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Дай Бог мне понять, что во что вложено... Буду ориентироваться по вашему описанию, а не по картинке. Если ошибусь, прошу прощения, надеюсь, смысл до вас смогу донести)

Если я не ошибаюсь, то модули = исполняемые коды, а не папки (хотя я могу ошибаться). Так что импортировать нужно именно коды, а не папки с ними.
Могу как решение вам предложить использовать изменение директории при помощи встроенного модуля `os`:

В итоге нужно будет записать такие выражения в файлах:

`GUI.py`:

```
import os #импортируем модуль для работы с системой
os.chdir('report') #изменяем действующую директорию на папку с нужным нам файлом для импорта
import report #импортируем нужный код: report.py
```

Аналогично в `report.py`:

```
import os
os.chdir('base_class') #переходим в папку base_class
import calc_base #импортируем calc_base.py
```

И давайте на засыпку объявим простую функцию в файле `calc_base.py`:

```
def func():
    print('Hello world!')
```

Обратите внимание, что дабы это многоступенчатое импортирование пошло, вам нужно записать строки кода, приведённые выше, просто так. Без всякого

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

Импортируя, Питон как бы выполняет импортируемый код, отсюда и появляются классы и, в нашем случае, модули.

Теперь, допустим, вы открыли командную строку в директории с файлом `GUI.py` и решили импортировать его. Посмотрим, что выйдет:

`командная строка:`

```
C:\Users\User>python
>>> #строкой выше мы запустили питон в нашей директории для работы с ним непосредственно в настоящем времени
>>> import main #импортируем main, помня, что он импортирует report, который в свою очередь импортирует calc_base, в котором функция func()
>>> #теперь смотрите, как нужно вызвать нашу конечную функцию:
>>> main.report.calc_base.func()
Hello world!
>>> #то есть сначала обращаемся ко всему, что есть в main.py, путём "main.", включая наш report
>>> #далее обращаемся ко всему, что есть в report.py, путём "report.", включая calc_base и так далее, пока не добираемся до func()
```

То есть, как вы видите, мы можем сделать сколь-угодно-ступенчатую структуру, которая будет ссылаться друг к другу через точки.

К вопросу, используется ли это: честно говоря, больше 2 ступеней не встречал и те использовались лишь для кода ВНУТРИ модуля, а через сам модуль не вызывались. Зачем вызывать модуль через другой модуль, если можно попросту вызвать их по отдельности? Хотя может я просто не встречал. Безусловно красиво, но, как по мне, не совсем удобно.

Но как видите, если очень захотеть, можно и такое провернуть!

---

Всем добра-бобра и удачи в написании кода!